# How to move one directory to another directory?

Tags: php, file

I have two folders

1. myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/iclean
2. myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/pics

I need to move **iclean** folder into **pics** folder using PHP.

Comment: is this an one off problem you have? Or you are going to do it regularly as part of a web application. If you are just looking for a file manager written in PHP you can use: http://pfn.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/function.rename.php). Note that if this runs on a web server, the web server user must have access to write to the target directory.

```
rename("oldpath", "newpath");

// in your case, assuming the script calling rename() 
// resides in the directory above 'myappdemo.com'
rename("myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/iclean", "myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/pics/iclean");

// Or use full absolute paths
rename("/path/myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/iclean", "/path/myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/pics/iclean");
```

Comment: hi put code i get Warning: rename(www.myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/iclean,www.myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/pics) [function.rename]: No such file or directory in /home/myappdemo/myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/getZip.php on line 55

Comment: @user816891 Clearly you've used the wrong path name. Your path is `/home/myappdemo/myappdemo.com/...` and you have specified `www.myappdemo.com/...`. You need to use the exact correct file path. That's a file path, not a URL path...

Comment: doesn't the example above RENAME the dir 'iclean' to 'pics' (replacing the 'pics' dir completely)? The task is to move 'iclean' inside 'pics', so should it not be rename("myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/iclean", "myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/pics/iclean"); ?

Comment: @mwb Yes it should have been. On the Unix command line, a `mv` would have placed it into the target directory which already existed.  PHP `rename()` would indeed replace it but fail if the target directory was not empty.

Answer (score 2):

There's a specific PHP function for it

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about SEO i recommend you using redirects 301 in your .htaccess.

That must be something like that:

```
RewriteRule ^/VueGuides/services/iclean  http://myappdemo.com/VueGuides/services/pics  [NS,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I required a different solution in my case as I was moving a sub folders contents into the parent folder. `rename` wouldn't work in my instance because the path was the same.

(For Linux based machines):

`exec('mv '.$this->useFolder.'/'.$sub_folder.'/*'.' '.$this->useFolder);`

This uses the inbuilt `mv` function through exec.