# How can I move a folder using CodeIgniter and/or PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to move a folder from one location to another.  I tried to accomplish this by copying using the code below:

```
copy ("old_location "," new_location ");
```

This isn't quite what I want.  I need to *move* the entire folder to another folder rather than copying the contents to a new location.  How can I do this using PHP and/or CodeIgniter

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to move one directory to another directory in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446247/how-to-move-one-directory-to-another-directory-in-php)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Just made a few edits to make the question read a little bit more clearly.  I think this still accurately reflects what you were asking!

Answer (score 0):

Two easy way :

- first read all path recursively and copy for each one
- more simple but you need to take care about file right by doing something like : shell_exec("cp -R old new")
  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php